How Capture ISAM error returned by Informix Db in C#.NET
I am currently using .NET provider for Informix to connect and work with Informix db. I have seen in Informix documentation that in an ODBC application we can use GetSQLDiagField function to get ISAM error. Are there any similar methods available to get the ISAM error in C# .NET?
I tried using the following dll but I'm only getting the primary error message and codes, not the ISAM error:

IBM.Data.Informix version 3.0.0.2
IBM.DATA.DB2 version 11.5.5

My .NET application version is 4.6.2

I don't think you can get it with the Informix .NET Provider but, based on https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=properties-message, the Data Server one (IBM.Data.Db2) should include the ISAM code in the text message.

If have have access to the IfxCommand.StatementHandle ISAM should be accessible with SQLGetDiagField(SQL_DIAG_SQLSTATE) but the StatementHandle is internal so I doubt you can get it.

Hi @jsagrera , can you please tell me how to call SQLGetDiagField function in c#? When I read about it, I got to know that only odbc application can access them or am I missing something here?  Thanks for your help!

The Informix .NET Provider (both .NET and .Net Core) use the Informix ODBC driver underneath. While you can Import DLL functions within C#  using System.Runtime.InteropServices, the parameters needed for the SQLGetDiagField call (like the internal ODBC statement handle) are not public, they are handled internally within the Provider (declared as internal).  Haven't test it, but the Db2 Provider should give you the ISAM in the text string. You may get the ISAM from there.

What would be the parameter name in which the ISAM error comes in DB2? I tried DB2 and i am getting the similar error exceptions as IBM.Data.Informix

I tried with the Informix provider and there is no way to get the ISAM. Even using Reflection to access the internal IfxStatement.StatementHandle the ISAM error is no longer there (reset to zero) because the provider will reset that value after the initial SQL call.
The DB2 one (Data Server Client) should have the ISAM within the message text. The DB2 doc link I pasted last week has something like  [IBM][CLI Driver][IDS/UNIX64] Cannot read system catalog (systables) (-144 ISAM error: key value locked.  -144 is an ISAM error

Tested with the DB2 provider (against Informix) and the ISAM error is definitely there in the error message. ERROR [42000] [IBM][IDS/NT64] The specified table (dummy) is not in the database. (-111 ISAM error:  no record found.)

I tried with EntityFramework version of db2 since ibm.data.DB2 is not compatible with my application, and i was not able to see ISAM error using  this dll, can you please tell me if you would have used  ibm.data.DB2 this dll?

The EF Provider is not the same as the .NET Provider. I'm not sure the EF will show the ISAM in the message, Yesterday I tested with the plain .NET Provider IBM.Data.Db2.dll from https://www.nuget.org/packages/IBM.Data.DB.Provider
